# Where to find a TYPO3 extension?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

What's the best practice to find a TYPO3 extension for my website? Where to look and how to find the best extension for my use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main source for finding a TYPO3 extension is the TYPO3 Extension Repository (TER): https://extensions.typo3.org.

There you can search and filter extensions and see if they support your TYPO3 version.

If you are using TYPO3 in [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) Mode, another source is https://packagist.org/.

There you can search for TYPO3 extensions using https://packagist.org/?type=typo3-cms-extension.

Notice that the TER also displays how to install an extension package with Composer if an installation is supported this way:

[image: "composer req georgringer/news" shown on https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/news/]